# Generalized Binomial coefficients identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Is it true that for $\beta \in (0,1)$, we have:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left| C^{\beta}_{k}  \right| = 1$$

where $C^{\beta}_{k}$ denotes the generalized binomial coefficient "beta choose k".

Sorry if this is something obvious. Haven't worked in this area before and it's appearing to me as an intermediary result for something else in another field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use $\binom{\beta}k$ to denote $C^\beta_k$.

The Taylor series for $(1+x)^\beta$ around $x=0$ is$$(1+x)^\beta=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\beta}kx^k,\qquad -1<x<1,$$
The fact that this converges in the region $-1<x<1$ is easy to show using the ratio test. However, we need to show this converges when $x=-1$. Supposing we can show this, then your result follows:
$$
0=0^\beta=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\beta}k(-1)^k=1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left|\binom{\beta}k\right|,
$$ 
where we have used $\left|\binom{\beta}k\right|=(-1)^{k-1}\binom{\beta}k$, valid for $k\ge 1$.

The series converges for $x\in (-1,1)$, and we want to show it converges at $x=-1$. Therefore, it suffices to show
$$
\lim_{x\to (-1)^+}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\beta}kx^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\beta}k(-1)^k
$$
To do this, we use the [monotone convergence theorem for series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_series). Writing this purported limit as 
$$
1-\left(\lim_{x\to (-1)^+}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)\binom{\beta}kx^{k}\right),
$$
then all the summands, $(-1)\binom{\beta}kx^{k}$, are positive real numbers, and each summand increases as $x$ approaches $-1$ (from the right). We can then apply MCT to interchange the limit with the summation.

Comment: Thank you, that's very clarifying. I arrived at the step completely removed from the context you provide and don't think I would have been able to formulate it as you present.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I've run into a number of road blocks recently of this variety in studying probability theory. My hunch is it boils down to a lack of discrete math background. Are there any references or resources you'd recommend to get up to a serviceable level in such tools and techniques from the discrete side that are used in other parts of math?

Comment: @anktsdmcknsy For this post, I think my knowledge of generating functions was most applicable, the best source for which is Wilf's _generatingfunctionology_. If you want your discrete math to include graph theory, a good introduction is Bryant, _Aspects of combinatorics_, with a wide foundational approach and approachable exercises and hints. If you that is too easy, then van Lint and Wilson's _A course in combinatorics_ is much more challenging and deep.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll check them out. @Mike Earnest.